# I can access a file on a network path, but I cannot save to the same path (C#) (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, comexception

This declaration has no problem accessing the file in  my network.

```
  MyApp = new Excel.Application();
  MyApp.Visible = false;
  MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open("//NetworkFolderPath/File.xlsx"); //This line
  MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1];
```

The problem arises when I am done editing my file and I try to save it, using the "SaveCopyAs()" method.

```
  MyBook.SaveCopyAs("//NetworkFolderPath/File2.xlsx");
  MyBook.Close(0);
```

The Exception I get is

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Application.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file    '//NetworkFolderPath/File2.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:

1. The file name or path does not exist.

2. The file is being used by another program.

3. The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open  workbook.
```

**For Number 1:**  The file does exist inside the folderm and I accessed the file via the path, so I have ruled out number 1.

**For Number 2:**  I am not sure if it could be this reason, some explanation would be nice

**For Number 3:**  I have given the workbook a different name, but I am not sure if this will solve the problem.

I am really not sure where to go from here. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have problems only with network path or local too?

Comment: Eliminate any permissions issues and possibly a more informative error by trying `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"\\NetworkFolderPath\File.txt", "hello");`

Comment: @Backs I can save to my Server.MapPath so, Local isnt a huge issue, but I need to dump multiple files into a network drive.

Comment: Please try to save it with closed xml.
http://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: Also make sure that you have given the fully qualified name or the network folder. like \\server\share\folder name

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this `path does not exist` error when Offline Files are turned on and there is corruption in the cache. Try resetting the cache using [the instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942974).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it saves my 2 weeks effort and the application is saving the pdf on sahredpath with secured id (Credential)
if you have any question please comment below !happy to help you

============================
public class Impersonate
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword,
                                            int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out int phToken);

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int FormatMessage(int dwFlags, string lpSource, int dwMessageId, int dwLanguageId,
                                            StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nSize, string[] Arguments);


    private const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8;
    private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
    private const int FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM = 0x1000;

    private static WindowsImpersonationContext winImpersonationContext = null;

    public static void ImpersonateUser(string domain, string userName, string password)
    {

        //Benutzer einloggen
        int userToken = 0;

        bool loggedOn = (LogonUser(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT,
                                    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out userToken) != 0);

        if (loggedOn == false)
        {
            int apiError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder(1024);
            FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, null, apiError, 0, errorMessage, 1024, null);
            throw new Exception(errorMessage.ToString());
        }

        WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity((IntPtr)userToken);
        winImpersonationContext = identity.Impersonate();

    }

    public static void UndoImpersonation()
    {
        if (winImpersonationContext != null)
        {
            winImpersonationContext.Undo();
        }
    }
}
```

2. Call Impersonate

```
        Impersonate.ImpersonateUser("domain", "user name", "password");
        //Your Code as the new User
        DirectoryInfo _dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"file path");
        FileInfo[] _files = FileExtension.GetFilesByExtensions(_dirInfo, ".xls", ".xlsx").ToArray();
        Impersonate.UndoImpersonation();
```

==============================

## Ref:- https://forums.asp.net/t/2126720.aspx?Access+Denied+while+reading+writing+directory+in+Network+File+Share+through+Service+Account